# Timeseries getting last required day of the month and repeating it

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

> 1. A dataframe has columns 'START', 'CLOSE', each
>      representing a date.
> 2. Another column 'WOM' week of the month is added to know which week of the month a given start date falls (between 1 to 5).
> 3. Another column 'END' is added having condition, if 'WOM' is less than 4 then used the same months last CLOSE as END else use next
>      months last close as END.

Following code does the above said, but doesn't produce correct END column:

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', '2018-06-27', freq='7D')
close = start.shift(1) - pd.Timedelta('1Day')
df = pd.DataFrame({'START':start, 'CLOSE':close}, columns=['START', 'CLOSE'])
#Week of the month
df['WOM'] = df.START.apply(lambda x: (x.day-1)//7+1)
#Get end list
ends = df['CLOSE']
ends.index = ends
ends = ends.resample('M').last()

def get_end(x):
    try:
        wom = x['WOM']
        st = x['START']
        me = ends.searchsorted(st)
        print(f'{st:%Y-%m-%d}_{wom}_{me[0]}')
        if wom >= 4:
            return ends.iloc[me[0] +1]
        else:
            return ends.iloc[me[0]]
    except:
        return None

df['END'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_end(x), axis=1 )
```

> Highlighted column in the image should have been 2016-07-26 instead of
>   2016-08-30, what is wrong and how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've solved it as following:
>
> 1. Removed WOM column
> 2. Finding the end using 'CLOSE' column instead of 'START' column

And here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
start = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', '2018-06-27', freq='7D')
close = start.shift(1) - pd.Timedelta('1Day')
df = pd.DataFrame({'START':start, 'CLOSE':close}, columns=['START', 'CLOSE'])
#Get end list
ends = df['CLOSE']
ends.index = ends
ends = ends.resample('M').last()

def get_end(x):
    try:
        wom =  (x['CLOSE'].day - 1)// 7+1
        st = x['CLOSE']
        me = ends.searchsorted(st)
        if wom >= 4:
            return ends.iloc[me[0] +1]
        else:
            return ends.iloc[me[0]]
    except:
        return None

df['END'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_end(x), axis=1 )
```

**I appreciate any other solution!**